# How to I setup a VoIP Server (not connected to telephony)

Tags: voip, mobile-broadband

What I need is a VoIP server that allows people use their data bundle to make calls within an app (mobile/PC), but not necessarily app to phone but App to App.

That means, both users have the app running and they don't need to have phone numbers.

- What would I need to know (I'm developing the App for Mobile - Android, BB, iOS)?
- What would the configuration of my server be (hardware requirements)?
- What are the software requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to develop the App yourself? I would choose one of the many apps already available.

First you need to decide what protocol you want to use. Users could just use [Skype](http://www.skype.com/en/) to communcate from Skype to Skype. Downside/Upside is you don't need a server of your own.

If you want to setup your own server you could go for the widely used [SIP-protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol).
[Here is a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Servers) of server-software. You can check out the pages to see the hardware requirements.

Two of the most used VOIP-servers are [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) and [Freeswitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/).

With these servers you can use one of the many [(SIP-)apps available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software#Clients).

Another possibility is choosing one of the many VOIP-providers on the internet. You need to choose one who does not charge you for calls between users. For example [Voipbuster](http://www.voipbuster.com/peer_to_peer) has free PC to PC (and App to App) calling. The mother-company of Voipbuster has many, many, many sub-companies who all have different rates of calling land-lines per country (which you don't need) but all provide free user to user calling. So you won't need your own server.

**Before deciding** which one of the options above you want, you need to test (and check) if your cell-provider does not block any of these protocols. Sometimes the provider blocks Skype and/or SIP-protocol via data because it hurts their business. In Europe there are laws (coming) against the blocking of these protocols but it's best to check beforehand.

Comment: thanks for the comment! But I need to clarify these:  
* I want to develop the App myself  
* The communication is from App to App, and would NOT need phone(s) at any point. SCENARIO: One user with the App (mobile or PC) installed on his mobile "calls" another with the App; he picks and they "talk"  
* I was told Asterisk could do just anything. Could it do this? Or would there be other dependencies?

Comment: If you have a Asterisk server you can connect with PC-Apps (supporting SIP), mobile-Apps and even SIP-phones (no need for landlines). They all can call each other via internet (without using landlines or cell-pans other than data) All the suggestions I made are App 2 App. You only need to decide if you setup your own (Asterisk-)server or use one on the internet (like Voip Buster)

Comment: I have an Asterisk-machine and can connect with an App on my phone to it. This way I can call other users also connected to the server. The App on my phone is [Sipdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua&hl=en) but there are many ([CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple&hl=en) is another) All these are for App 2 SIP-server 2 App. You can try to build your own App using the SIP-protocol (Asterisk supports both its own AIX/AIX2 protocol and SIP protocol).

Comment: Using your own Asterisk server and Apps on the computer and phones there is nothing further you need. But make sure you read the last paragraph about cell-providers blocking some protocols. Otherwise you're going to a lot of trouble setting it up, just to find your provider is blocking it.

Comment: Thanks, @rik! It's getting pretty clearer. It's the last paragraph that actually confuses me. I presumed that since communications are all based on data (that is, over the Internet), I wouldn't have any issues with the cell provider. What I need to get clearly is how the "protocol" has anything to do with my cell provider, when the connection is "only over the Internet" (data). Please clarify this. Thanks, Rik!

Comment: Because you're going to use Apps to do "voice over internet" the providers are **NOT** happy you're doing it over cheap data-connection (compared to expensive minutes) So, sometimes they block VOIP-applications. See [here](http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/42640?start=0&tstart=0) for such a discussion. Even if they are not blocking, they can slow down some ports over internet to discourage VOIP-usage. And even if you use different ports (then the default ones) they have equipment in place to detect VOIP-traffic. All to keep you from doing chat via App 2 App. So check if they don't do that.

Comment: I perfectly understand better!!! Thanks, Rik! Now, my research has a clearer direction...